# Tengo un pequeño gran problema

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una funcion que manda un valor a un textarea, el problema es que esta en un while el href con la funcion,osea que hay varios href con diferentes valores,enves de mandar el valor de ese href me manda el valor del ultimo href del while.

```html
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>
  <script>
  function cita(){
    document.form1.a_answer.value = '<a href="#<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>">'+'>'+<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>+'</a>'
  }
  </script>
<div id="<? echo $rows['a_id'];?>">
<a href="#" onclick="cita()"><?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?></a>
```

ese es una parte del codigo, mas abajo esta el form al que mando los valores.
desde ya gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Hola, lo que observo es que el while se abre se cierra el tag de php, pero donde se cierra el tag del while después ? Creería que por ahí puede venir el problema.

Comment: termina al final de una tabla, pero ahora estoy viendo y resulta que el script esta funcionando bien, realmente voy a tener que seguir indagando porque no se cual es el error concretamente

Comment: Procura que el título de tu pregunta indique qué ocurre o tratas de hacer, pues así cómo está no es descriptiva

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tienes un error de logica.  La funcion no debe de ir dentro del `while`.  Suponiendo que tengas 500 filas, vas a declarar la funcion 500 veces?  La forma correcta seria declarar la funcion fuera del ciclo y paserle el parametro que quieres.  Algo asi:

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
<script>
  function cita(a_id){
    document.form1.a_answer.value = '<a href="#' + a_id + '">'+a_id+'</a>'
  }
</script>
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>      
<div id="<? echo $rows['a_id'];?>">
<a href="#" onclick="cita(<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?>)"><?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?></a>
```